# PrimeNG DataView and p-fieldset giving unexpeted behaviors in angular 13

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a small angular app in which I want to use **DataView** and **p-fieldset** to display some informations. This is the view:

```
          <p-dataView #dv
          [value]="defaultRoles"
          [paginator]="true"
          [rows]="5"
        
          >
            <p-header>Default roles</p-header>
            <p-footer></p-footer>
            <ng-template pTemplate="listItem" *ngFor="let role of defaultRoles"  class="float">
                <p-fieldset legend={{role.designation}} [toggleable]="true" class="p-fieldset">
                  <div class="p-fieldset">
                    {{role.description}}
                </div>
                </p-fieldset>
            </ng-template>
          </p-dataView>
```

I imported correctly the DataView and p-fieldset in **appModule** and in the **authModule** where the component is called:

```
import { FieldsetModule } from "primeng/fieldset";
import { DataViewModule } from "primeng/dataview";
```

But the p-fieldset style is not applied as demonstrated [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-primeng-fieldset-component/). Also the iteration `*ngFor="let role of defaultRoles"` only displays the last element in the array 5 times.
[image]

As you can see on image only the role sec-med' data is displayed 5 times corresponding to the `[rows]="5"` that I set in the `<p-dataView>` tag. But the defaultRoles data is defined in component as below:

```
  defaultRoles = [
    { designation: "Super-Admin", description: "An Administrator provides office support to either an individual or team and is vital for the smooth-running of a business. "},
    { designation: "Admin", description: "Their duties may include fielding telephone calls, receiving and directing visitors"},
    { designation: "Med", description: "Administrators are usually required to use Microsoft Office and should demonstrate proficiency with Microsoft Word,"},
    { designation: "Sec", description: "Knowledge with Xero or MYOB packages can be an advantage."},
    { designation: "Sec-med", description: "The Administrator provides office support to either an individual or team and is vital for the smooth-running of a business. Le Rôle Secretaire Medecin est celui attribué à  rapproché au medecin chargé superviseur des secretaires"}
  ];
```

As you can see the p-fieldset is broken and only the role sec-med which is the last in the array is the only one displayed 5 times. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong for the **p-fieldset** not taking proper PrimeNG style, and why the **defaultRoles** array data is not completely display. I will appreciate your help to get into the right path. Thanks in advance.